# Android - How to pass object of a view from XML with data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am building an Android application in which I am using Data binding library. I am little new to `Data binding` concept and looking for the solution for the following

There is a layout file called **otp_validation.xml**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="otpViewModel"
        type="dial.to.go.otp.OTPViewModel" />
</data>
<ConstraintLayout
 .....................
 .....................
 .....................
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/otp_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/all_edit_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/all_edit_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp" />

</LinearLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
          
          <!-- I want to pass the view object of otp container as a parameter in the method validateOTP()
            android:onClick="@{() -> otpViewModel.validateOTP()}"
           
            android:src="@drawable/drawable_fab_proceed"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />
           
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Please notice the method `validateOTP()` being invoked in `onClick` event. I would like to send the view object of linear layout (otp_container) as a parameter. Please help me out for providing me the solution for this.

Comment: You should not pass the view to the view model.

Comment: @HimanshuChoudhary, Okay. I want to get the LinearLayout and read the values of it children. How to achieve this ?

Comment: A better deal would be to call the `onClickListener` programmatically inside the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the view which is clicked then you can do it

```
android:onClick="@{(view)->viewModel.onOthers(view)}"
```

To pass a view other than the clicked view, pass the id,

```
android:onClick="@{(view)->viewModel.onOthers(otpContainer)}"
```

Note that the signature of the method should be like

```
fun onOthers(view:View){
  //your code goes here
}
```

So that it can allow any type of view.

**UPDATE**
`otp_container` will be `otpContainer` for `Binding`.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of binding objects to an XML would pretty much be the same, create those objects in the activity/fragment class, initialize the corresponding variables in the XML file and use binding to bind the objects and variables.

Try the following

**Activity class**

```
val yourLinearLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.otp_container)
binding.view = yourLinearLayout
```

**XML File**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="otpViewModel"
        type="dial.to.go.otp.OTPViewModel" />

    <variable
        name = "view"
        type = "android.widget.LinearLayout"
</data>

//rest of the logic

     <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        ..........          
        ..........
        android:onClick="@{() -> otpViewModel.validateOTP(view)}"
        ..........
        ........./>
```

Though it works, its indeed a bad practice. `Viewgroup` must know **nothing** about the views because if the activity/fragment gets destroyed/recreated, the view references in the viewgroup would lead to memory leaks